# Reading/writing image data from X clipboard and converting to SDL_Surface

Tags: c, linux, sdl, clipboard, x11

When I select "Copy Image" in a browser, or use a screenshot tool to screenshot to clipboard, I am able to directly paste those pixels as selections in programs like `gimp`. In my SDL-based Linux image editor, I want to fully support handling this data in the same way `gimp` does.

To be clear, I am specifically talking about image *data*, not *files* (copying an abstract "image file" in a filesystem browser vs. copying the raw pixels of an image), whereas most of what I've found by searching is related to handling the copy/pasting of image files as a whole, something I have no interest in.

My problem is: I can't seem to find exactly what I libraries/functions I need to link to and make use of to do this.

Every result I get searching terms like `paste image data clipboard x11 linux` or `image data clipboard sdl` is either related to handling files which happen to be images (I want image *data*), shell-specific (I'm writing a C program using SDL2), or just generally unhelpful.

What libraries and functions should I be looking to use to read/write raw image data from clipboard, and how can I convert said data into a format compatible with `SDL_Surface` (and vice versa)?

*Note: In case affects anything compatibility-wise, I use* `parcellite` *as my persistent clipboard manager, and I'm unsure if it uses* `xclip` *internally, but* `gimp` *seems to handle it fine.*

Comment: What do [the SDL2 clipboard functions](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryClipboard) return when you try to paste image data?  Nothing?  Giant base64-encoded strings?  Raw byte strings?  Filenames in `/tmp`?  Doesn't look like [SDL's X11 backend does anything too fancy](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/59004900db7f/src/video/x11/SDL_x11clipboard.c).

Comment: I *think* you can listen for a [`SDL_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_EventType) event to be reasonably sure `SDL_GetClipboardText()` will return something useful.  As opposed to polling `SDL_HasClipboardText()`.

Comment: Trying to paste image data obtained from `copy image` and similar with `SDL_GetClipboardText()` always returns a `NULL` string (or the first byte is always 0 for some odd reason, but they are functionally the same), while obtaining actual text in the clipboard works fine.

Comment: Oof, [this](https://github.com/dacap/clip) is [looking](https://jtanx.github.io/2016/08/19/a-cross-platform-clipboard-library/) to be a real [shitshow](https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=24823), good luck!  [clip](https://github.com/dacap/clip) is a thing that exists (quality unknown) if you're willing to wrap a C++ library.